# How do I change the cryptsetup background?

Tags: disk-encryption, cryptsetup

When I encrypt my disk/OS, GNU/Linux shows a screen or image on boot where you can type in your password. How do I edit that image/change it?

---

I am currently on Debian, which includes a black background during cryptsetup.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth

Answer (score 0):

You should override `/usr/share/images/vendor-logos/logo-text-version-64.png` and install Plymouth themes.

```bash
cd /usr/share/images/vendor-logos/
sudo mv logo-text-version-64.png logo-text-version-64.png.bak
sudo cp your-image.png /usr/share/images/vendor-logos/logo-text-version-64.png
sudo apt-get install plymouth-themes
sudo plymouth-set-default-theme -R spinner
```

Update `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`, then

```bash
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot your machine and you should be fine.